# How would I use the return data from a controller as EJS data?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, ejs

I have a Node.js application in development which tries to get a list of clients. It uses the latest version of Express and Passport.

I'm trying to achieve retrieving the return data from a controller method, and use EJS to pass through the data to the view.

Please see my code below.

**routes.js**

```
var clientController = require('../app/controllers/clientController');

// Dashboard page.
// This should be protected, the user has to be logged in to make a request.
app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    var clientData = clientController.findAll;

    console.log(clientData) // This outputs '[Function]'

    res.render('dashboard.ejs', { user: req.user, clients: clientData })
})
```

**clientController.js**

```
const Client = require('../models/client');
var clientController = {}

clientController.findAll = function(req, res) {
    Client.find(function (err, clients) {
        res.send(clients)
    });
};

module.exports = clientController;
```

**dashboard.ejs**

```
<!-- I'm trying to keep it simple at the moment. -->
<%= clients %>
```

The current behaviour of the app, is that it would simply output the raw Javascript code.

> function (req, res) { Client.find(function (err, clients) { res.send(clients) }); }

I don't get any errors in the console (apart from the `[function]` I mentioned earlier)

If I was to change the route to `app.get('/dashboard', clientController.findAll)` it somewhat works, it would only display a Json output to the user. This is something I don't want. I was hoping I could call other controllers and "merge" them in the same response.

If anyone would help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: `clientController.findAll;` this just returns you function reference. You need to call it like `clientController.findAll()`

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Thanks for commenting. I tried doing that, and I got the error of `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`. I tried calling it as `clientController.findAll(req, res)`, and I got a `Can't set headers after they are sent.` I'm very much assuming I would need to pass in something. Either that or modify the `findAll()` method.

Comment: just saw your full code. They way you're trying to achieve things is not valid. `req` and `res` are only defined for the callback functions you mention in routes. That's why you get this error

Answer (score 0):

There are issues the way you are trying to achieve it. First of all you are defining a route handler as anonymous and then trying to call a controller method with wrong syntax.

`var clientData = clientController.findAll;` Here not using `()`.

Also your controller method is expecting `req,res` and in your controller you have used `res.send()` which will send response back to client will never return data back to route handler.

You should use following approach a better and more cleaner one:

Instead of going for using `clientController` for dashboard, you should create one `dashboardController` and use it as follow:

**routes.js**

```
const clientController = require('../app/controllers/clientController');
const dashboardController = require('../app/controllers/dashboardController');

//simply use dashboardContrller.index as route handler
app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, dashboardController.index);
```

**dashboardController.js**

```
const Client = require('../models/client');
const dashboardController = {}

dashboardController.index = function(req, res) {
    Client.find(function (err, clients) {
      res.render('dashboard.ejs', { user: req.user, clients: clientData });
    });
};

module.exports = dashboardController;
```

This way you won't have to worry about returning data back or anything also any dashboard related logic can be put inside this controller.

Also instead of using `callbacks` I would recommend reading about `Promises` and using these.